# Ideas about generating images for E-Paper display

Tags: embedded, flash, display, ram

I am currently working on a project where I'm using a [DA14531 BLE-module](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/da14531-module-datasheet) to collect data from some sensors and display the collected data on an [E-paper display](https://www.pervasivedisplays.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/1P190-00_01_E2417FS052_20180511.pdf). As the display is quite large (400x300 pixels), it results in relatively large frames (400x300 bits = 15kB). I would, however, not want to use more than 10kB for this application.

The data will be displayed in the following fashion:

Outside temperature: 24°C 
Inside temperature: 20°C 
Pressure: 101,325 Pa 
Inside humidity: 25%

This means most of the pixels will stay the same color all the time while only the data values will change. Is there some clever way to only store part of the image on the module, and generate the rest? In other words, store all the possible numbers and characters and generate the rest of the image on the go.

Comment: depends completely on the controller as to what what where and how you update the display, and if you can even update a portion of the display without doing a full refresh.  some yes some no, some you have to do a refresh every so often anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is. You already said how it's done. You keep whatever fixed parts such as text as single image and then apply glyphs from a font for numbers you need.